# Lucene data range search

Tags: lucene, umbraco7

I'm using Umbraco v7.2 for a site, and have run into a highly entertaining issue trying to search for things using the External Searcher by a date of ranges.

If I perform a Lucene search using the examine management search tools in the backoffice, I get results using this query:

```
{(+__NodeTypeAlias:bookingperiod)} AND startDate:2016-03-01T00\:00\:00
```

Subsequently, I KNOW that I can get results that include this date in a range. However, what's highly entertaining, quite puzzling and really rather frustrating, is that if I use a range query, I get no results. Here's the syntax:

```
{(+__NodeTypeAlias:bookingperiod)} AND +(startDate:[2016-02-28T00:00:00 TO 2016-03-20T00:00:00])
```

Now, in the interests of clarity, I've tried escaping the colon characters in the dates, the dashes in the dates and both, but it makes no difference at all. Can anyone explain to me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a while back, not sure why though, but changing to the format :"yyyyMMddHHmmss" helped, might be something with the parser.

So the query becomes:

```
+__NodeTypeAlias:bookingperiod AND +startDate:[20160228000000 TO 20160320000000]
```

Comment: No results, I'm afraid!